# Spring @GetMapping doesn't work for child resource

Tags: spring, spring-restcontroller

I have a controller looks like this.

```
@RestController("/some")
public class SomeController {

    @GetMapping(produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<?> read(...) {
        ...
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "{id:\\d+}", produces = ...)
    public ResponseEntity<Some> readSingle(@PathVariable(name = "id") final int id) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The controller works for parent.

```
curl http://.../some
```

But the child resource returns the same with `/some`.

```
curl http://.../some/2 // returns the same with /some
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: It has to be `/`{id:\\d+}

Comment: `My kingdom for a forward slash` - me the other day when I made the same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering for my own question.

The problem is the wrong annotation on the class.

```
@RequestMapping(path = {...})
@RestController
public class SomeController {
}
```